# VBA to sum up multi worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, sum

I'm building a Budget template in Excel and getting a problem in Consolidation sheet.

I'm looking for a VBA can help me to auto sum up data from projects sheets. Please see the picture below.

Need to Sum up all project sheets per month and per account
[image: Need to Sum up all project sheets per month and per account]

It will be the same if we put the formula like:

```
Consolidation!D2 = sum(A!D2, B!D2, C!D2)

Consolidation!D3 = sum(A!D3, B!D3, C!D3)
...

Consolidation!E2 = sum(A!E2, B!E2, C!E2)
Consolidation!E3 = sum(A!E3, B!E3, C!E3)
...
```

I know we can put a formula like: `Sum(A:C!D2)`,etc... but really need it with a VBA code.

Comment: Either write that formula into the cell using VBA (which I recommend) or you need to loop through all sheets and sum those values in a loop (google for tutorials how to loop through sheets). • Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FI4HkCzMaIk it may help solve the problem and give you more flexibility. It provides an introduction to appending data using inbuilt functionality (which is easier to maintain). You will have to adapt it for your specific needs but there's a great starting point. I've used this append approach quite a few times recently and it's proved to be a real time saver.

Comment: Please note that link only answers tend to get useless to future readers as links might disappear after a while. See [answer]. At least put the main idea in your answer as solution and only use links for additional information. The answer post **itself** needs to give a solution to solve the original problem in the question.